# Multiple Custom UICollectionView on Multiple Custom TableviewCell between section

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uicollectionview, swift3

**Multiple Custom UICollectionView on Multiple Custom TableviewCell**

What I want:
Multiple Custom UICollectionView on Multiple TableviewCell.

￼
These differ by section.

I followed this Tutorial : https://ashfurrow.com/blog/putting-a-uicollectionview-in-a-uitableviewcell-in-swift/

but I couldn't figure out why problem happens,

The errors shows,

> Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'could not dequeue a view of kind: UICollectionElementKindCell with identifier ProductCell - must register a nib or a class for the identifier or connect a prototype cell in a storyboard'

I registered Nib File from cellForRowAt,
also Of course I added identifier on Nib file.

from TableView's method, like this

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    switch indexPath.section{
    case 0:

        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: product, for: indexPath) as! ProductTableViewCell
        cell.collectionView.register(UINib(nibName: "ProductCollectionViewCell", bundle: nil), forCellWithReuseIdentifier: "ProductCell")

        cell.collectionView.viewWithTag(0)
        return cell
    case 1:
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: cellIdentifier, for: indexPath) as! ShowDataTableViewCell
        cell.collectionView.register(UINib(nibName: "ShowDataCollectionViewCell", bundle: nil), forCellWithReuseIdentifier: "CollectionCell")
        cell.collectionView.viewWithTag(1)
        return cell

    default:
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: cellIdentifier, for: indexPath) as! ShowDataTableViewCell

        cell.collectionView.register(UINib(nibName: "ShowDataCollectionViewCell", bundle: nil), forCellWithReuseIdentifier: "CollectionCell")
        cell.collectionView.viewWithTag(99)

        return cell
    }

}
```

This doesnt work, and also I try to register nib file, from TableViewCell,

But its also doesnt work.

Or Problem is occur from numberOfItemsInSection method?

```
extension TableChildFoodViewController : UICollectionViewDelegate, UICollectionViewDataSource{

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int{
        return 10
    }

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell{


        print("tag: \(collectionView.tag)")


        switch collectionView.tag{
        case 0:

            let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "ProductCell", for: indexPath) as! ProductCollectionViewCell
            return cell

        case 1:            
            let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "CollectionCell", for: indexPath) as! ShowDataCollectionViewCell
            return cell


        default:
            let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "CollectionCell", for: indexPath) as! ShowDataCollectionViewCell
            return cell
        }


    }

}
```

If possible Can you give me advice?

[TableChildFoodViewController.swift](https://gist.github.com/yosuke1985/c94d766ef356ea4e152dfa2b06b4cf7d)

Comment: Are you sure you have identifier called "ProductCell". please check for any typos.

Comment: Yes Im really sure added that identifier on nib file

Comment: Try swapping those two lines.  (register before you dequeue)

Comment: @Nitya what do you mean? how swap? which code?

Comment: What is product in following line?    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: product, for: indexPath) as! ProductTableViewCell Isnt it should be "product"?

Comment: @Nitya That is the identifier of UITableViewCell of Nib File.

Comment: I uploaded this controller's code, [TableChildFoodViewController.swift](https://gist.github.com/yosuke1985/c94d766ef356ea4e152dfa2b06b4cf7d)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/126633/discussion-between-nitya-and-yosuke).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved,

I should have on this method

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell
```

not , cell.collectionView.viewWithTag(0)

I fixed, cell.collectionView.tag = indexPath.section

Thats worked!